# Get user's guild nickname

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I have a discord bot that gets the nicknames of people, but nicknames do not seem to be exposed to me. The username is accessible however, the nickname is not:

```js
client.on('interactionCreate', async interaction => {
var username = interaction.user.username; //accessible
```

I have also tried: `interaction.member.displayName` and looked at options under `interaction.user` however been unable to find something that allows me to get nicknames!

Comment: username = nickname, so I assume you are trying to get full user tag and not just username? or do you want to get user nickname on specific server?

Comment: I meant nickname for the channel - username would return their discord username, but in server, everyone changes their username to their full name (its a discord bot to help make teaching online easier) and we would get their username but not full name

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look at [the documentation](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMember?scrollTo=nickname) you can see that to get a nickname you just need [`interaction.member.nickname`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMember?scrollTo=nickname)

Note:

- [`Member`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMember) may be [`null`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/null), for example if the interaction was not done in a guild, but in a private messages (DM)
- [`.nickname`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMember?scrollTo=nickname) can be [`undefined`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/undefined) as the member may not have one

Comment: `interaction.member.displayName` will be the member's username if they don't have a nickname, if they do, it will be the nickname